# what is the differnce between entity framewok and massive ORM?

Tags: entity-framework-4, massive

I had been researching on various ORM when I came across  ORM called "Massive". Can anyone give me the difference between Massive and Entity framework 4. Which one is better?

Comment: "which is better" is impossible to answer, without knowing your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework is from Microsoft whereas Massive is a third-party, light-weight Micro-ORM. It is not a matter of better or poor.

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines it sounds like you've not used an ORM before?  Your question is hard to answer as it is comparing apples with oranges.  I would suggest picking something like EF and trying it out. Have fun!